# Laravel 5 response json

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

I want to return simple json from my controller.

This code returns me json, but wrapped with html tags and script:

```
public function getSomething($request) {
       return response()->json(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA']);
    }
```

But when I use this code:

```
public function getSomething($request) {
       return json_encode(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA']);
    }
```

I get clear json response without any html tags.

How can I turn off some html wrapper in the first code, I need only clear json response from my function.

Thanks in advance.

**I think problem in chrome not in laravel response, it adds some wrap to my response**

Added:
**No I have the same problem in ie too, and my second code wrapped with html too, I can't understand what is the problem. Anybody can help me? Thanks.**

Added:
OK when I use die in my function all works fine for me

```
public function getSomething($request) {
           die json_encode(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA']);
        }
```

but when I use **return json_encode(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA']);** laravel wrap my response with html and with js script...
something like this:

```
<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump...
```

**I have found the BIG mistake in my code, I used dd in one my function after return the data from it, and dd wrap my response. So... my bug is resolved!!!**

Comment: How do you verify what is in your response?

Comment: I go to mysite/ajax, in my routes.php I added special route. I can see result in browser, I checked in ie and in chrome I got the same result. Also I checked in chrome console my ajax request and response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the BIG mistake in my code, I used **dd** in one my function after return the data from it, and **dd** wrap my response.